# Update PWA icon on android

Tags: android, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I created a React PWA app and I thought how would my icon update on the home screen if I already added a first version ?
I tried to update the manifest but nothing changed.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you profile using chrome dev tools to see if the changed manifest came in? By default, your changes will reflect on your next visit. Try closing your app from the list of app and open again. Service worker will notice Hash code for manifest file is changed and it will download, which will be applied on next load.

Comment: Of course, the changed was notice on Chrome dev tools. You mean I have to delete the APK then reinstalling it from Chrome Android?

Comment: No. I didn't mean to delete and reinstall, as we can't expect the end users to do the same, if we have the same scenario. When you connect your phone to your desktop and open chrome dev tools, you can do the remote debugging of your installed PWA(as its just a full screen web opens in chrome). Follow this and give us more insights on whats happening on service worker update, icons. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: If you can share the URL, that would be much easier for the community to find the issue.

Comment: When you install the app, does it have a little browser icon to the lower right of your icon on the devices homescreen?

Answer (score 0):

Changes aren't reflected immediately. In most cases, changes should be reflected within a day or two of the PWA being launched, after the manifest has been updated.

When the PWA is launched, Chrome determines the last time the local manifest was checked for changes. If the manifest hasn't been checked in the last 24 hours, Chrome will schedule a network request for the manifest, then compare it against the local copy.

If [select properties](https://web.dev/manifest-updates/#cr-android) in the manifest have changed, Chrome queues the new manifest, and after all windows of the PWA have been closed, the device is plugged in, and connected to WiFi, Chrome requests an updated WebAPK from the server. Once updated, all fields from the new manifest are used.

Full details are at https://web.dev/manifest-updates/